# NSSavePanel not saving on desktop?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

can i use NSSavePanel with a sandboxed OS X app to let user save on desktop? i gave user read/write entitlements for downloads and user selected folder, for some reason my app saves in downloads folder fine but when i change directory and select desktop it doesnt save at all.

here is the code am using for NSSavePanel

```
if([self.mActiveQRFileName isEqualToString:kQR_DEFAULT_FILE_NAME])
    {
        NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
        //[savePanel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[Utilities getQRDefaultDirectoryPath]]];
        [savePanel setNameFieldStringValue:kQR_DEFAULT_FILE_NAME];
        [savePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:[self window] completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
            if (result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton) {
                NSString *qrFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[[savePanel URL] path],kQR_FILE_EXT];

                [qrd saveQRFile:qrFilePath];
                self.mActiveQRFileName = [NSString stringWithString:qrFilePath];
                blnChangesSaved = YES;
            }
        }];
    }
    else
    {
        [qrd saveQRFile:self.mActiveQRFileName];
        blnChangesSaved = YES;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I am not sure, but it can be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NSSavePanel` will give you the user selected path for a file in it's `URL` property. The sandbox will only grant you access to this file, with the name specified by the user.

In your example code this line possibly modifies the selected path by giving it a different file extension:

```
NSString *qrFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",[[savePanel URL] path],kQR_FILE_EXT];
```

Which could result in a filename different from the originally selected file for which you don't have access in the sandbox. Try logging the `qrFilePath` and see if it still equals the path for the selected URL. Also check your sandbox exceptions to see what the exact error is.

If you want to restrict the `NSSavePanel` to let the user only specify files of a certain type use the `setAllowedFileTypes:` methos.

If you want the user to grant you access to a directory to write to where you can output any file, as opposed to a specific path: use a `NSOpenPanel`. This has the disadvantage that the user cannot specify a specific file name like in a `NSSavePanel`.

Comment: tried logging and this is what i get 
--- 
You don’t have permission to save the file “adfasdf.png” in the folder “Desktop”. 
--- 
2/3/13 10:30:31.243 PM sandboxd: ([1970]) QR Code Generato(1970) deny file-write-create /Users/Zahid/Desktop/adfasdf.png

Comment: Yes, so it indeed looks like you are writing to a different location than the user specified in the `NSSavePanel`. That is happening because you're appending a different file extension in the line I mentioned in my answer. You don't have permission to write to a URL other than what's exactly returned by in `[savePanel URL]`.